# How can I properly call this WinAPI function from Rust which requires an i8 buffer?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

**(Using winapi crate)**

I am having a little difficulty being able to figure out how to use WinAPI functions in rust without examples. I feel like I *almost* have it... but am having some problems translating the WinAPI types to my Rust types. I am not quite sure how I am supposed to determine it.

I am attempting to call the [GetGeoInfoA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getgeoinfoa) (hyperlinked to microsoft docs).

Here is my current code attempt:

```
unsafe {
    let mut geo_data: Vec<i8> = Vec::new();
    let result =  GetGeoInfoA(2, 0, &mut geo_data[0], geo_data.len().try_into().unwrap(), 0);
    println!("GEO RESULT: {:#?}", String::from_utf8(mem::transmute(&geo_data[..result as usize])).unwrap());
    };
```

athlough I am getting:
"cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
source type: `&[i8]` (128 bits)
target type: `Vec<u8>` (192 bits)"

... Which, I rather expected. I feel like I am approaching the problem wrong all together though.

For instance, how do I know where to get "GeoType", which the function calls for in it's second parameter? It's asking for a u32, so I am guessing the different options are indexed and selected by index? Where am I able to find this information?

At the end of the day, I need to just figure out how to get the **GetGeoInfoA** function to work, although any extra tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a homemade declaration for the function, or from a known crate such as `windows` or `winapi`? If it's homemade, please show it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Sorry, using winapi crate.

Comment: I recommend that you work with the `windows` crate instead of the `winapi` crate. It is the official crate from Microsoft.

Comment: Hint: you need to invoke the function once to determine the size of the buffer, allocate it then invoke it the second time with the buffer. The `transmute()` isn't needed: use `Vec::set_len()` then `String::from_utf8()`.

Comment: `&mut geo_data[0]` - this is a C/C++ construct that does not translate to Rust like that :/

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things wrong with your code:

- Don't do `&mut geo_data[0]`. This is an old C++ pattern, and even in C++ it is deprecated. Use `geo_data.as_mut_ptr()` instead.
- Don't toss in a `transmute` just to fix things - `transmute` can break many things and should be used with much care and only if the person using it absolutely understands what it does. In your case, it's not just ineffective, it's wrong and dangerous.
- In your attempt to convert the `Vec` to a `String`, you are mixing up owned vectors and slices. If you take a sub-slice (via `&geo_data[..result as usize]`), you cannot convert this to a `String`, as it doesn't own the data. You could create a `&str` from it, though, of course. But if you want to resize a `Vec`, use `.resize()` instead.
- You need to actually create some buffer that the data can be received into; the `Vec` you created is empty. Fill it with some zeros.
- The parameters of your function are incorrect and will return `0`, indicating an error.
- Your `Vec` has the type `i8`, while the `String` expects `u8`. As those two types are binary compatible, you could change the `Vec` to `Vec<u8>` and convert the pointer to it to an `i8` pointer.

With all those things fixed, here is some working code:

```rust
use winapi::um::errhandlingapi::GetLastError;
use winapi::um::winnls::GetGeoInfoA;

fn main() {
    let mut geo_data = vec![0u8; 10];

    let result = unsafe {
        GetGeoInfoA(
            2,
            6,
            geo_data.as_mut_ptr().cast(),
            geo_data.len().try_into().unwrap(),
            0,
        )
    };

    if result == 0 {
        let err = unsafe { GetLastError() };
        println!("Query failed with error: {}", err);
    } else {
        // Cut off the excess data
        geo_data.resize(result as usize, 0);
        println!("GEO RESULT: {}", String::from_utf8(geo_data).unwrap());
    }
}
```

```
GEO RESULT: de-ag
```